# how to 301 example.com/xxx/feed to example.com/xxx/ in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I need to remove the url's feed by using htaccess.

I use `RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/feed/?$ /[R,L]`

But it can't direct the url

> http://www.example.com/xxx/feed

to right url

> http://www.example.com/xxx/

I don't know too much about htaccess.

If you can tell me how or give me some advice to learn how to do it, it's really thank you for your help.

Just redirect the url:example.com/xxx/feed to example.com/xxx/ in htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/feed/?$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

OR using `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.+?)/feed/?$ /$1/
```

Comment: RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.+?)/feed/?$ /$1/ worked for me~ thank you. Have a nice day~